# Bind9 one spf record for all zones

Tags: bind, spf

I want to create one include with SPF IP address to be used from all dns zones in my server. Can you suggest me how to do it? I work on BIND9. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

- The bind zone file syntax provides an `$INCLUDE` statement to *"include"*  content/resource records from a different file into the zone.

See for example: https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/include.html where the zone file for the uk.example.com zone includes a second file `/var/named/include.txt`

```
$ORIGIN uk.example.com.
@          IN      NS     ns2.example.com. 
; ns2.example.com services uk.example.com

$INCLUDE /var/named/include.txt ; absolute path
...
ftp        IN      A   192.168.35.16
```

That second file, `/var/named/include.txt` can then be something like:

```
  # when this /var/named/include.txt is included 
  # it sets up a generic SPF record for the zone

  @   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:10.9.8.7 -all 

  # EOF /var/named/include.txt
```

- The alternative approach uses the native SPF `include` directive to include the SPF record values from another domain:

  ```
    "v=spf1 a mx include:example.com. -all
  ```
- A similar alternative approach uses the native SPF `redirect` directive to use the SPF record from another domain:

  ```
    "v=spf1 redirect=example.com
  ```

Both the native SPF methods come with their own caveats, explained here: https://dmarcian.com/spf-syntax-table/